# Add the user ID on the URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass a User `id` onto the URL. Once I click on the icon, it should redirect to a specific page with datatables.

And I should see the ID appended on the url

Here are my codes, JS, Controller and Route. But it is not working.

```html
<a class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon btn-round" href="{{ url('pages/sms-history'.$sms-history->user_id) }}" title="SMS History">
    <i class="material-icons">sms</i>
    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
</a>
```

Controller:

```php
public function getView($id)
{
    $smshistory = SmsOutboundsHistory::find($id);

    return view('pages.sms-history')->withSmshistory($smshistory);
}
```

Route:

```php
Route::get('/pages/history/{id}', 'HistoryController@getView');
``
```

Comment: my href is inside the ajax file, and it will not parse the {{(())}}
I was able to get a workaround for this. I'm posting my answer on a different post. Incase anyone will search for the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

What is the resulting URL ? You are not showing the most important information, the final URL you get for you to say "it is not working"...

You are also not showing what `withSmshistory` does... So, I am assuming `$sms-history` does exist in your view and it has no typo...

**But that is pretty akward, as `$variable-something` is not valid, because you are subtracting `$variable` with `something`... so, check that please and share your code correctly please...**

I am assuming your problem is how you defined the `url` (as the helper, not the `Route`).

So, try this:

```php
url('pages/sms-history', ['id' => $sms-history->user_id])
```

And if it does not work or gives errors, try this one:

```php
url('pages/sms-history', [$sms-history->user_id])
```

See more information about [`url`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a slash in the url. You're appending user_id without adding a slash, so your current code will generate  sms-history1, sms-history2, etc ( assuming all other issues are fixed )

```php
Route::get('/pages/history/{id}', 'HistoryController@getView')->name('pages.history');


public function getView($id)
{
    $smshistory = SmsOutboundsHistory::find($id);
    return view('pages.sms-history', compact('smshistory')); 
}


<a class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon btn-round" href="{{ route('pages.history', $smshistory->user_id) }}" title="SMS History">
    <i class="material-icons">sms</i>
     <div class="ripple-container"></div>
</a>
```